# How to merge two pandas DataFrames based on a similarity function?

Tags: python, pandas, merge, fuzzy-comparison

Given dataset 1

```
name,x,y
st. peter,1,2
big university portland,3,4
```

and dataset 2

```
name,x,y
saint peter3,4
uni portland,5,6
```

The goal is to merge on

```
d1.merge(d2, on="name", how="left")
```

There are no exact matches on name though. So I'm looking to do a kind of fuzzy matching. The technique does not matter in this case, more how to incorporate it efficiently into pandas.

For example, `st. peter` might match `saint peter` in the other, but `big university portland` might be too much of a deviation that we wouldn't match it with `uni portland`.

One way to think of it is to allow joining with the lowest Levenshtein distance, but only if it is below 5 edits (`st. --> saint` is 4).

The resulting dataframe should only contain the row `st. peter`, and contain both "name" variations, and both `x` and `y` variables.

Is there a way to do this kind of merging using pandas?

Comment: I think you can create new columns `df1['new']` and `df2['new']` your custom function and then merge them by this column like `d1.merge(d2, on="new", how="left")`

Comment: The function is just deciding which is the best match, and deciding whether or not there is a match at all. Consider the later added Levenhstein distance example.

Comment: Great question! Did you come up with a solution @PascalVKooten?

Answer (score 7):

Did you look at [fuzzywuzzy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fuzzywuzzy)?

You might do something like:

```
import pandas as pd
import fuzzywuzzy.process as fwp

choices = list(df2.name)

def fmatch(row): 
    minscore=95 #or whatever score works for you
    choice,score = fwp.extractOne(row.name,choices)
    return choice if score > minscore else None

df1['df2_name'] = df1.apply(fmatch,axis=1)
merged = pd.merge(df1, 
                  df2,
                  left_on='df2_name',
                  right_on='name',
                  suffixes=['_df1','_df2'],
                  how = 'outer') # assuming you want to keep unmatched records
```

Caveat Emptor: I haven't tried to run this.

Comment: I wonder how we can record the matched score along the matched choice? 

Inspecting the distribution of scores, can better guide a meaningful choice for the threshold. 

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have that function which returns the best match if any, None otherwise:

```
def best_match(s, candidates):
    ''' Return the item in candidates that best matches s.

    Will return None if a good enough match is not found.
    '''
    # Some code here.
```

Then you can join on the values returned by it, but you can do it in different ways that would lead to different output (so I think, I did not look much at this issue):

```
(df1.assign(name=df1['name'].apply(lambda x: best_match(x, df2['name'])))
 .merge(df2, on='name', how='left'))

(df1.merge(df2.assign(name=df2['name'].apply(lambda x: best_match(x, df1['name'])))),
           on='name', how='left'))
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest idea I can get now is to create special dataframe with distances between all names:

```
>>> from Levenshtein import distance
>>> df1['dummy'] = 1
>>> df2['dummy'] = 1
>>> merger = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['dummy'], suffixes=['1','2'])[['name1','name2', 'x2', 'y2']]
>>> merger
                     name1         name2  x2  y2
0                st. peter   saint peter   3   4
1                st. peter  uni portland   5   6
2  big university portland   saint peter   3   4
3  big university portland  uni portland   5   6

>>> merger['res'] = merger.apply(lambda x: distance(x['name1'], x['name2']), axis=1)
>>> merger
                     name1         name2  x2  y2  res
0                st. peter   saint peter   3   4    4
1                st. peter  uni portland   5   6    9
2  big university portland   saint peter   3   4   18
3  big university portland  uni portland   5   6   11
>>> merger = merger[merger['res'] <= 5]
>>> merger
       name1        name2  x2  y2  res
0  st. peter  saint peter   3   4    4

>>> del df1['dummy']
>>> del merger['res']
>>> pd.merge(df1, merger, how='left', left_on='name', right_on='name1')
                      name  x  y      name1        name2  x2  y2
0                st. peter  1  2  st. peter  saint peter   3   4
1  big university portland  3  4        NaN          NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: This wouldn't scale with larger frames. I have a mere 6000 by 6000 matching, but that would explode using this technique.

Comment: well you can of course speed it up a bit - first join those which are exact match and then use levenshtein thing only on remaining ones

Comment: The point is that you create at first a 2 x 2 x num_vars sized frame. That would mean a 6000 x 6000 x num_vars sized frame....