# String matching and store results as lists in cells

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, loops, fuzzy-comparison

I have two very large tables df1 and df2 (multiple millions of rows each) of person-related data and each table has a column that contains the name of a person (column name: "Name"). The names of one and the same person can be written differently (e.g. "Jeff McGregor" or "Mr. J McGregor", etc.) among the two tables, which is why I want to apply fuzzy string matching with the fuzzywuzzy package in Python (this simply compares two strings and returns a similarity measure).

As an output (see df3 for the desired output table), I would like to fill the "Match_Flag" and the "Match_List" columns in the df1 according to the entries in df2. For every (unique) person in df1, I want to check if there are (fuzzy string) matches in the df2. If there is a string, the column "Match_Flag" should contain a "yes" and if not, a "no". The "Match_list" column should contain for every name a list of matches. If there is one match, the list would contain one entry and if there are e.g. three matches, the list would contain 3 matches. If there is no match, the list should be just empty.

This is the data:

**df1**

```
data_df1 = {'ID':[56382, 34732, 12423, 29574, 76532], 
           'Name':['Tom Hilley', 'Andreas Puthz', 'Jeff McGregor', 'Jack Ebbstein', 'Lisa Norwat'],
           'Match_Flag':["", "", "", "", ""],
           'Match_List':["", "", "", "", ""]} 

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data_df1) 

print(df1)

      ID           Name Match_Flag Match_List
0  56382     Tom Hilley                      
1  34732  Andreas Puthz                      
2  12423  Jeff McGregor                      
3  29574  Jack Ebbstein                      
4  76532    Lisa Norwat
```

**df2**

```
data_df2 = {'Name':['Tom Hilley', 'Madalina Peter', 'Russel Cross', 'Jenni Pey', 'Kanush Hawks', 'Mr. J McGregor', 'Ebbstein Jack', 'Mr. Jack Ebbstein'],
           'Age':[16, 56, 33, 44, 24, 26, 86, 32]} 

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data_df2) 

print(df2)

                Name  Age
0         Tom Hilley   16
1     Madalina Peter   56
2       Russel Cross   33
3          Jenni Pey   44
4       Kanush Hawks   24
5     Mr. J McGregor   26
6      Ebbstein Jack   86
7  Mr. Jack Ebbstein   32
```

**df3**

```
data_df3 = {'ID':[56382, 34732, 12423, 29574, 76532], 
               'Name':['Tom Hilley', 'Andreas Puthz', 'Jeff McGregor', 'Jack Ebbstein', 'Lisa Norwat'],
               'Match_Flag':["yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "no"],
               'Match_List':[["Tom Hilley"], [], ["Mr. J McGregor"], ["Ebbstein Jack","Mr. Jack Ebbstein"], []]} 

df3 = pd.DataFrame(data_df3)

print(df3)

     ID           Name Match_Flag                          Match_List
0  56382     Tom Hilley        yes                        [Tom Hilley]
1  34732  Andreas Puthz         no                                  []
2  12423  Jeff McGregor        yes                    [Mr. J McGregor]
3  29574  Jack Ebbstein        yes  [Ebbstein Jack, Mr. Jack Ebbstein]
4  76532    Lisa Norwat         no                                  []
```

**My approach:**

```
# import libraries
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz  

# create matching
for i in df1["Name"].unique().tolist():

    # initialize matching list
    matching_list = []

    for j in df2["Name"].unique().tolist():

        # create matching score
        if fuzz.token_set_ratio(i, j) >= 90:
            matching_list.append(j)

    # create red flags
    if matching_list:
        df1.loc[df1['Name'] == i,'Match_Flag'] = 'yes'
        df1.loc[df1['Name'] == i,'Match_List'] = matching_list
    else:
        df1.loc[df1['Name'] == i,'Match_Flag'] = 'no'
        df1.loc[df1['Name'] == i,'Match_List'] = ["-"]
```

**Output of my approach:**

```
line 611, in _setitem_with_indexer
    raise ValueError('Must have equal len keys and value '

ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

Since my approach is 1. not working and 2. **it will be way too slow for millions of rows**, I ask you to help me and find a more efficient and working approach please.

Answer (score -2):

base on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35380933/how-to-merge-two-pandas-dataframes-based-on-a-similarity-function) I believe merging those two dataframes are a lot more efficient than iterate through the whole data.
since you want matched names, you should use inner join.

Comment: fuzzy match is giving an approximation of match, not _exact_ match, thus a join wont work. Normally I would probably just cross join the two tables (not matching on anything), and .apply the function, but multi million row dataframes would create a trillion+ row dataframe which wouldn't work.

Comment: this is a bit different, you can see in the topic that there a bit of pre-processing there to make this join fuzzy

Comment: oooh interesting. I didn't see the link. That might work!

Answer (score -2):

This answer might take a while to run, but should work.

I imported names to create larger dataframes with random names.

```
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz 
import random
import os
import names



id_col = range(10000)
name_col = [names.get_full_name() for _ in range(10000)]
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':id_col, 'name_col':name_col})

age = [random.randint(1, 95) for _ in range(10000)]
name_col2 = [names.get_full_name() for _ in range(10000)]
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name_col2':name_col2, 'age':age})
```

Since we want to iterate through df1, I dropped duplicates of the name column. We're going to do a cross join to bring the whole row of the dataframe into the 2nd dataframe, so I assigned v=1

```
df1_deduped = df1.drop_duplicates('name_col')
df2 = df2.assign(v=1)
```

define the fuzzy function to use in `.apply`

```
def func(row):
    return fuzz.token_set_ratio(row['name_col'], row['name_col2'])
```

Here we're going to loop through the length of the first dataframe, and for every row (unique name), we're joining it to the 2nd dataframe. We then `.apply` the fuzzy function to a tokenthresh column, and filter down the dataframe by the threshold 70. If there are any matches, it writes it to a csv. This way it's not all done in memory which will mostly likely be an issue for you with multi-million row dataframes on both sides. This will chunk it into pieces. Alternatively instead of going row by row into a million row dataframe, you could do it in 5s or 10s, that could slow it down, I'm not sure.

```
for i in range(len(df1_deduped)):
    df3 = pd.merge(df1.assign(v=1).iloc[[i],:], df2, on='v').drop(['v'], axis=1)
    df3['tokenthresh'] = df3.apply(func, axis=1)
    df3 = df3[df3.tokenthresh > 70]
    print('there are', len(df3), 'records that exceeded the threshold')
    if len(df3) > 0:
        df3.to_csv(str(i)+'.csv', index=False)
```

We then can read in the files that were created:

```
files = []
for file in os.listdir():
    files.append(pd.read_csv(file))
data = pd.concat(files)
```

and lastly concat the different answers:

```
data['concat_group'] = data.groupby(['ID', 'name_col'])['name_col2'].transform(lambda x: ', '.join(x))
data = data.drop_duplicates(['ID', 'name_col'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution!  Unfortunately, I get an error message: "ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 7, saw 5". Also, it would be way to slow for the size of my data :/

Comment: post the error? with the created datasets this does at least work. did you look into phalanx's link?